# actors in a stage not responding to touch

Tags: android, libgdx

I had a problem with actors in a stage which not responding to touch

Here what i did :

first i made a class TestActor

```
public class TestActor extends Image {
    public TestActor(Texture t) {
        super(t);
    }
}
```

I draw this texture using Sprite and draw method of Image at a specific 
position.

then i made this class

```
public class MyActor extends TestActor {
    public MyActor() {
        super(new Texture("img.png");
        // adding input listener to test it
        addListener(new InputListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                if(button == Buttons.LEFT) 
                    System.out.println("actor is touched");
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

then i made a stage class to hold copies of MyActor

```
public class MyStage extends Stage {
    MyActor[] actors;
    public MyStage() {
        // I add these actors to the stage and draw them each in a 
specific position
    }
}
```

then i draw this stage in MyScreen

```
public class MyScreen implements Screen {
    MyStage stage;
    public MyScreen() {
        stage = new MyStage();
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    }
}
```

everything goes as i want except for clicking on any of the actors which 
give me nothing

where is the problem ?

Comment: Did you forget to call stage.act(); ?

Comment: no I call it
drawing actors is fine

Comment: please show a code of MyScreen render where you are call stage.act()

Answer (score 1):

You have to set size of actor, also try to use `debug` method on actor and check its bounds first.